# Rounding 2 decimal places with DecimalFormat using default Locale

Tags: java, android, decimalformat

How can I get only TWO decimal places regardless of the locale.  I know I can use `DecimalFormat` to manually format like `"0.00"` if I wanted, but I want to get th proper decimal type in the user's locale AND round to two places.

```
DecimalFormat dFormat = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
etPayment.setText(dFormat.format(p)); // How would I do it on this line?
```

Comment: [NumberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMaximumFractionDigits-int-) perhaps?

Comment: @VGR  I completely forgot about that.  I have used that before.  For some reason my IDE (Android Studio) doesn't recognize any of the set functions with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DecimalFormat currencyFormatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());

currencyFormatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2); // << This should
currencyFormatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2); // << do the trick

System.out.println(currencyFormatter.format(-123456.7812));
```

Will output:

```
-123,456.78
```

Or if you have a locale like `Locale.GERMANY`:

```
-123.456,78
```

**Update: (Simple copy & paste)**

```
DecimalFormat dFormat = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
dFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2); // << This should
dFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2); // << do the trick
etPayment.setText(dFormat.format(p));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");`

Comment: I mentioned above I can do that, but that does not take into account all user's locale.  Some users rather see `0,00` instead of `0.00`.  Is there a universal way to round AND use default locale was my question.